# Angular Mat-Table expand specific row when page is loaded

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a table with expandable rows. When I click on the row it works fine. But I want a specific row to expand when I load the page. I already have the index of the row I want to expand.

This is the HTML I have:

```html
<mat-table>
   <!-- columns-->

   <mat-row
      [matTableDetailsRow]="row"
      [matTableDetailsRowTpl]="tpl"
      [rowIndex]="index"
      (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)"
   ></mat-row>
</mat-table>

<ng-template #tpl let-element>
   <div [@detailExpand]>
      <!-- expanded content -->
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

This is the function that expands and collapses the rows:

```js
    public onToggleChange(detailRow: MatTableDetailsRowDirective): void {
        if (this.openedRow && this.openedRow.expanded) {
            this.openedRow.toggle(false);
        }

        this.openedRow = detailRow.expanded ? detailRow : undefined;
    }
```

how do I expand and collapse the row programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried to work with viewChild.

So I suggest to add in HTML component #detailRow.

```
      <mat-row
      #detailRow
      [matTableDetailsRow]="row"
      [matTableDetailsRowTpl]="tpl"
      [rowIndex]="index"
      (toggleChange)="onToggleChange($event)"
   ></mat-row>
```

and in TS component add viewChild

```
  @ViewChild('detailRow') detailRow: MatTableDetailsRowDirective;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.detailRow.toggle(true);
  }

  public onToggleChange(detailRow: MatTableDetailsRowDirective): void {
    if (this.openedRow && this.openedRow.expanded) {
      this.openedRow.toggle(false);
    }

    this.openedRow = detailRow.expanded ? detailRow : undefined;
  }
```

ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook is used to toggle the row when the component's view has been initialized.

Btw: With more row then one you need to used ViewChildren instead of viewChild and filter in QueryList.